# Is there an R/caret equivalent of scikit-learn's labeled kfold cross validation?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, r-caret, cross-validation

I'm augmenting my data and i want to make sure that related data are not separated into different folds during cross validation.

I know scikit-learn has a labeled k-fold algorithm that takes in a list of labels along with the data set and assures that the same label is not found in 2 different folds. Is there an equivalent of this in R? I'm using the caret package for my regression modeling.

Answer (score 0):

The [mlr package](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/index.html) seems to have that sort of functionality. The ['blocking'](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/task/index.html#further-settings) option specifically specifies that all observations within a block must be included together when resampling occurs. If you aren't too attached to the caret package, you consider using this.

Comment: I would prefer to use caret if at all possible, but I will take it into consideration. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#customizing-the-tuning-process

Use `trainControl` with `method = "cv"` and `number = 5` or whatever number of folds you're looking for. There is also a `"repeatedcv"` method which will resample the data.